# Create on update and delete cascade

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, cascade

i have a query to delete cascade, here the query

```
create table satuan_type
(
    id int identity(1,1),
    satuan_id int(200),
    type_id int,
    primary key(id),
    foreign key(satuan_id) references satuan(id) on update cascade on delete cascade
);
```

the question is, how to create / add, delete and update cascade with c#?. so the query is running/crete automatically in this method

```
Dictionary<String, String> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dic.Add("id", "INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY");
dic.Add("satuan_id", "INT");
dic.Add("type_id", "INT");
cDatabaseSQLServer.CreateTables("satuan_type", dic);

public int CreateTables(String tableName, Dictionary<String, String> data)
{
    switch (sqlType)
    {
        case DATABASE_SQL_TYPE.DATABASE_SQL_TYPE_SQLITE:
            return cSQLite.CreateTables(tableName, data);
        case DATABASE_SQL_TYPE.DATABASE_SQL_TYPE_MSSQL:
            return cSQL.CreateTables(tableName, data);
    }
    return 0;
}

public int CreateTables(String tableName, Dictionary<String, String> data)
{
    string s = "CREATE TABLE " + tableName + " (";
    bool first = true;
    foreach (KeyValuePair<String, String> val in data)
    {
        if (first)
        {
            first = false;
        }
        else
        {
            s = s + ",";
        }
        string s1;
        s1 = String.Format("{0} {1}", val.Key, val.Value);
        s = s + s1;
    }
    s = s + ")";
    return this.ExecuteNonQuery(s);
}
```

Comment: delete cascade is more often than not a bad idea.

Comment: If you are going such a length, use an ORM. Much easier and better in doing things.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add logic to your CreateTables-method. Preferably you add more parameters in which you can input any keys that you want constraints on. Cause from what I'm reading at the moment, you are not creating any constraints at all. This is possible by iterating the same logic you've already used, but for primary and foreign keys respectively - preferable with a boolean variable-flag to mark if they should be cascaded or not.

Although, I suggest you do as MSI suggested and use an ORM.